# JSON TO HTML ROW USING PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to convert JSON into a list using PHP, Tried code below but cannot make it work

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://feeds.mse.mk/service/FreeMSEFeeds.svc/ticker/JSON/8BA941D0-D6E6-44BD-8D8B-47FDB7A563FA");
    $data =  json_decode($json);

    if (count($data->stand)) {
        // Open the table
        echo "<table>";

        // Cycle through the array
        foreach ($data->stand as $idx => $stand) {

            // Output a row
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$stand->AvgPrice</td>";
            echo "<td>$stand->Description </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        // Close the table
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

And I want to show list as here (not as a table):

http://prntscr.com/no1479

Comment: Well, your code is explicitly outputting an HTML table.  What other HTML did you want to output?  Just a series of `<span>` elements?  Something else?  What did you try?

Comment: your **$json** is already a json why are you decoding it. also it does not contain __stand__..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your all code is right but you can use stand class that is wrong your class is GetTickerJSONResult and so change the class stand to GetTickerJSONResult.

try this modified code..

```
 <?PHP
     $set =json_decode($json);
      if (count($set->GetTickerJSONResult)) {
       echo "<table>";
       foreach ($set->GetTickerJSONResult as $idx => $stand) {

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>$stand->AvgPrice</td>";
          echo "<td>$stand->Description </td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
        echo "</table>";
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because in `$data->stand` there is nothing.